# Data from google maps or bing maps available for offline use? Whole cities, I mean

Tags: google-maps, bing-maps

I was developing some graph-based search algorithms and it would be interesting to use them against some real data. I used openstreetmap against them (downloaded some city-wide OML files from some obscure site), and it all worked well until I started noticing that the data wasn't that trustworthy -- the data near my house had wrong highways directions, and there were roads that weren't properly connected.

I was wondering whether I could download full-city google or bing (or actually, any found to be trustworthy source) maps data for this same batch processing? What I basically need is access to all the streets (and to know whether they are one or two-way streets) of a given town of my choice (Lisbon, for instance), as a combination of vertex + edges, or any other format that will let me gather that info, for offline use.

Answer (score 1):

When you say download, I assume you mean for free.  You may be able to find something here http://gis-lab.info/qa/vmap0-eng.html which will be good enough for testing.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that I'd need the data to be free. That link you gave seems interesting, but I'm afraid it doesn't go into the level of detail I'd be looking for (having individual streets), as well as omiting other kind of info (if the street is one or two-way).

Comment: That kind of data with directionality almost always costs money, unfortunately in your case. OSM is really the best you can do.. as far as I can think without my morning caffeine... you can always edit the data, after all.